# Passing Intent filter actions to Audible

Tags: android

I am trying to open Audible from within an app and start Audible playing on launch.  Audible launches fine but does not start playing.

The Audible Manifest file contains:

```
<receiver
android:name="com.audible.application.WidgetReceiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.audible.application.app.PAUSE" />
    <action android:name="com.audible.application.app.PLAY" />        
    ...
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have created an Intent and set the Action to that specified in the Manifest file.  However, Audible launches but doesn't start playing.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =  getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.audible.application");
                if (intent != null) {
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    // Set Intent Action as defined in Audible Manifest 
                    intent.setAction("com.audible.application.app.PLAY");
                    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Cannot launch Audible!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

What else can I try to get Audible to start playing on launch?

UPDATE:
I've managed to get Audible to start and play using OK Google. First I need to open the app then start it playing.

- OK Google open Audible
- OK Google play

Therefore what I want to do is possible.  But I don't know what "OK Google play" calls under the surface to make the current player burst into life.

Comment: did you succeed in opening and playing the file on audible? how do you pass to audible the track to play?

Comment: No - I didn't get it to play.
Instead I created a different solution using MP3s

Comment: do you mean playing local mp3 files in your android app? or passing an mp3 file to audible to be played?

Answer (score 0):

```
        //open audible
        val intent =
            packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.audible.application")
        intent?.let { startActivity(it) }

        //simulate pressing the media play button after 1 second
        Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                (getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager).run {
                    dispatchMediaKeyEvent(
                        KeyEvent(
                            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                            KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
                        )
                    )
                    dispatchMediaKeyEvent(
                        KeyEvent(
                            KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                            KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
                        )
                    )
                }

            }
        }, 1000)
```