# How to open a specific Audible trackid from my app

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to open a specific audio track in audible from my android app.

My app has a button and clicking it I want to open Audible android app on the trackId I pass as extra and have the play started automatically.

Is it possible?

I tried [Passing Intent filter actions to Audible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57855272/passing-intent-filter-actions-to-audible) but it doesn't pass to audible the track information about what to play.

Has anybody tried to perform this?

Thanks!

Comment: This also interests my application. I keep following this thread