# Control Audible playback from my own custom Android app

Tags: mobile

I would like to provide a way for a cognitively impaired user to control Audible on their phone. Assistant control via speech is not an option due as the phone no longer understands their speech. The "normal" phone interfaces are too confusing for them.

My current ideal would be a very simple phone app with a giant play/pause button that controls Audible playback and absolutely nothing else. Another person can set up Audible to play the correct audio book and then turn the custom app on using "App pinning" or "Guided Access" mode so that they can't accidentally close the app and get lost.

So far I've researched iOS and Android approaches to accessibility (Guided Access, App pinning) and things like `AppIntent` on iOS, but I can't find any Audible specific API documentation. I'm struggling to know what to search for.

I'm technology agnostic here, I just want to solve the problem and am willing to learn to do it. iOS or Android are both fine.

---

Possible option with some different search terms: [Passing Intent filter actions to Audible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57855272/passing-intent-filter-actions-to-audible)